# How to apply side borders to table columns till footer

Tags: java, eclipse, dynamic-reports

I have a table with 3 columns and I tried to apply vertical lines for each column using left border and right border. the problem is, border is applying only when row data is present. but my requirement is to get the lines till footer even though data is not there

Comment: show code. id say you can replace not existing data with empty data to have the rows still being displayed

Comment: Sorry i didn't get u properly, please explain with clarity

Comment: as i understand it you want to show borders no matter if data is there or not. a simple solution would be to simply fake not existing data with empty data. meaning if you have a string which would be null, you replace it with " "

Comment: Actually i have some data in summary which is dynamic, and we cannot assume the number of rows present in a table then how can i pass null value, is it possible?